# Как закрыть view нажатием на свободное место вне этого view?

Tags: java, android, интерфейс, cardview

Есть Floating Button, при нажатии на которую появляется cardview, а fab исчезает.

```
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.map_cardview);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            fab.hide();
            cardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы этот же cardview закрывался при нажатии на свободное место во фрагменте (данная область отмечена на скиншоте красным цветов) и снова появлялся fab?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как я сделал, но анимация срабатывает на других кнопках в фрагменте

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test_item, container, false);

    fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.map_cardview);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            fab.hide();
            cardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });

    mRootView = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rootView);
    mRootView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fab.show();
            cardView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });

    return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно в layout в котором все это находится присвоитьid. Дальше в mainActivity нужно найти ваш linear layout например:

```
private LinearLayout mRootView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_message_center);

  mRootView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_root);
}
```

и дальше уже обработка нажатия:

```
mRootView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    fab.show();
    cardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
});
```

в итоге все будет выглядеть так:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_message_center);
  mRootView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_root);
  mRootView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      fab.show();
      cardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      mRootView.setOnClickListener(null)
    }
  });
}
```

должно работать, если возникнут сложности - не стесняйтесь и пишите, поможем чем сможем. Удачи :)

### update

```
fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    cardView = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.map_cardview);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            fab.hide();
            cardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mRootView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    });
```

Comment: В Google Maps меню выбора слоев и типов карты открывается по нажатию кнопки,а закрывается по нажатию вне этого view. Но там скорее всего используется другой метод.

Comment: у вас получилось достичь цели используя мой метод? или возникли сложности?

Comment: ,цель достичь получилось, но все остальные элементы, находящиеся в данном фрагменте перестают отвечать на нажатие.

Comment: ааа, так это у вас фрагмент??)) вы можете поставить enabled(true) возле всех остальных элементов, либо отключить слушатель нажатий на вью

Comment: сработало, вот только анимация продолжает срабатывать и на других элементах (при закрытие cardview они все показывают анимацию нажатия)

Comment: Обработчик клика на `mRootView` устанавливайте в методе по клику на FAB, и после клика на `mRootView`, в его обработчике вызывайте `mRootView.setOnClickListener(null)`

Comment: @VasilBaymurzin, анимация все равно срабатывает и на других кнопках

Comment: а само нажатие я так понимаю не осуществляется?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko,  остальные кнопки теперь работают, на когда cardview закрывается с помощью layout - анимация срабатывает на всех кнопках фрагмента

Comment: как-то странно честно говоря, можно конечно глушить анимацию на всех кнопках поодиночке, но вообще должно все работать как нужно) может переработать метод закрытия карточки?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, добавил в конце вопроса свой код

Comment: `mRootView.setOnClickListener(this);` внутри внутри обработчика `fab.setOnClickListener` установит для `mRootView` обработчик нажатия для `fab`, так как `this` здесь указывает на обработчик, установленный для `fab`.